# I can't get the login session with Facebook SDK 3.1.1

Tags: facebook, session, authentication

I'm trying to develop a Facebook application, and I have uploaded my `index.php` file, and I get this error when I run it (I use the new Facebook SDK 3.1.1):

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook::getSession() in /home/onlyimg/public_html/facebook/beworkstar/index.php on line 4

#### Code

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    /* Get a valid session */
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    $me = null;

    if($session) {
        /* Check if session is valid */
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
    }

    if($me) {
        echo 'User is logged in and has a valid session';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Session expired or user has not logged in yet.
        Redirecting...';
        echo '<script>top.location.href="'. $facebook->getLoginUrl()
        .'";</script>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the new [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/) but you haven't updated your code. Check the latest [SDK example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php).

Here's a rewrite of your code:

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if($user) {
    try {
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo 'User is logged in and has a valid session';
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        $user = null;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Session expired or user has not logged in yet. Redirecting...';
    echo '<script>top.location.href="'. $facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>';
}
?>
```